# Why weren't these answers quoted external sources closed?

Tags: discussion

GS didn't close this post that just quoted external source, but did recently close new posts that did. Did the policy change? Is this a contradiction?

[Why would a stock opening price differ from the offering price?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/24982/why-would-a-stock-opening-price-differ-from-the-offering-price#comment109230_69278)

[image]

https://money.stackexchange.com/a/4477

Comment: See [What is a closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-on-hold-or-duplicate-question)

Answer (score 6):

Answers can't be closed. Only questions can be closed.

Answer (score 3):

As moderators, we act on content that has been flagged, or that we come across and feel requires action. We don't generally go trawling the site for every possible thing that might not be in keeping with the rules.